# WordPress: Extend heading block in Gutenberg with extra options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to use normal `<h2>` tags in the editor as well as `.h2` classes for SEO reasons.
So instead of the `<h2>` tag I want to add something like this: `<p class="h2">`.

I found a way to add custom styles to a Gutenberg block with this code:

```
wp.domReady( () => {

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/heading', [ 
        {
            name: 'default',
            label: 'Default',
            isDefault: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'alt',
            label: 'Alternate',
        }
    ]);
} );
```

But this only adds some classes.
Is there any way to change the tag of the headline itself?

I know that I could add an extra style to the paragraph block.
But that would be a paragraph block and not an headline ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Gutenberg Editor, by using a `core/paragraph` block, you can add your custom CSS classes via:
*Block (Paragraph) > Advanced > Additional CSS Class(es)*:
[image]

This way, you can continue using Heading Blocks for `<h2>` tags and use Paragraph Blocks with the Additional CSS class `.h2` added to the published post/page.

Comment: That is a way you could go. I thought there was an option to change the headline block. But for now I'm going with the style in the paragraph block.